# WSL2 apt update failing with errors using old-release sources

Tags: apt, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to do an apt update, but I get these errors. Originally I put in the old-release source list. I'm not sure if that messed anything up. How can this be resolved?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Revert the sourcelist to what it was before you changet to old-releases ... Why did you change that at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver is not an `old-releases`. It is supported release.

So you have to replace the repo-lines by `archive` back.

Doing this programmatically is possible by executing:

```
sudo sed -i "s|old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic|archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic|g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And then run `sudo apt-get update` as usual.